# ReactJS: Sort e mapping on dynamic value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a value that change when the user chooses the type of sorting and a type of ordering:

```
paginationState.sort 
paginationState.order
```

paginationState.sort is equal to some values ​​that are contained within an array of objects
So for example if the user click on field "description", paginationState.sort will be equals to "description", while paginationState.order is equals to "asc" or "desc"

this field "description" is also inside the array of objects:

```
applicationList: [
{
  id: 1,
  description: "Example1",
  name: "Name2"
},
{
  id: 2,
  description: "Example2"
  name: "Name1"
},
.....
]
```

So I show the data of applicationList inside a table and clicking in the field title "description" i'll sorting the value in ascending or descending order for the "description" field.

So to make the sorting I have used:

```
<tbody>
              {[]
                .concat(applicationList)
                .sort((a, b) =>
                  paginationState.order === 'asc'
                ? a.description.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.description.toLowerCase())
                : b.description.toLowerCase().localeCompare(a.description.toLowerCase())

                )
                .map((application, i) => (
                <tr>.........
```

And it works.

Now my problem is that "description" is not the only field that can be chosen for sorting

So for example if I click on the table's title "Name", the paginationState.sort will be equal to "description" e so the sorting should be:

```
        <tbody>
              {[]
                .concat(applicationList)
                .sort((a, b) =>
                  paginationState.order === 'asc'
                ? a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase())
                : b.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(a.name.toLowerCase())

                )
                .map((application, i) => (
                <tr>.........
```

Now my problem is:

How can I use the `paginationState.sort` value in the So take the field in the object array depending on its value?

Something like (it doesn't works)

```
 const [typeSorting, setTypeSorting] = useState(paginationState.sort)
 .....
 {[]
                .concat(applicationList)
                .sort((a, b) =>
                    paginationState.order === 'asc'
                      ? a[`${typeSorting !== null ? typeSorting: null}`].localeCompare(b[`${typeSorting !== null ? typeSorting: null}`])
                      : b[`${typeSorting !== null ? typeSorting: null}`].localeCompare(a[`${typeSorting !== null ? typeSorting: null}`])
                )
                .map((application, i) => (
```

It is possible? Have you some ideas?

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
{typeSorting !== null ? []
                .concat(applicationList)
                .sort((a, b) =>
                  paginationState.order === 'asc'
                    ? a[typeSorting].localeCompare(b[typeSorting])
                    : b[typeSorting].localeCompare(a[typeSorting])
                )
                .map((application, i) => (
                  <tr key={`entity-${i}`} data-cy="entityTable">
```

But I receive error that `a[typeSorting].localeCompare` is not a function

Comment: Are you getting an error that you can share? Have you tried checking for null first and skipping the sort function? And then if not null you can just compare `a[typeSorting]` and `b[typeSorting]`

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I don't check the null value of typesorting. So you suggest to try something like ```.sort((a, b) => typeSorting !== null ? // Compare....// : null? )```

Comment: I'm suggesting you check if `typeSorting` is null before even performing the `.sort` call - `if (typeSorting) { [].concat(applicationList).sort((a, b).....}`

Comment: So I have tried but I receive error a[typeSorting].localeCompare is not a function

Comment: Which field did you select for sort? Id would throw that error because it’s a number

Comment: yes the error is because paginationState.sort is inizialized with the id

Comment: There isn't a way that I could sort also the id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
const [listSorting, setListSorting] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
if (applicationList && applicationList .length > 0) {
  sortingList();
}
}, [props.applicationList ]);

const sortingList = () => {
const list = [].concat(applicationList).sort((a, b): any => {
  if (typeof a[paginationState.sort] === 'string') {
    const variableA = a[paginationState.sort].toUpperCase();
    const variableB = b[paginationState.sort].toUpperCase();
    if (paginationState.order === 'asc') {
      return variableA < variableB ? -1 : variableA > variableB ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (paginationState.order === 'desc') {
      return variableA < variableB ? 1 : variableA > variableB ? -1 : 0;
    }
  } else if (typeof a[paginationState.sort] === 'number') {
    const variableA = a[paginationState.sort];
    const variableB = b[paginationState.sort];
    if (paginationState.order === 'asc') {
      return variableA < variableB ? -1 : variableA > variableB ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (paginationState.order === 'desc') {
      return variableA < variableB ? 1 : variableA > variableB ? -1 : 0;
    }
  }
});
setListSorting(list);
};
```

and in the return

```
{listSorting && listSorting.length > 0 ? (
      <table className="table table-striped">
   //.......

 <tbody>
          {listSorting.map((app, i) => (
            <tr key={`entity-${i}`} data-cy="entityTable">
```